# Buildozer with twisted fails because it cannot find incremental

Tags: python, kivy, twisted, buildozer

Buildozer fails with kivy and twisted.

```
working: distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('incremental>=16.10.1')  
working: Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/incremental/: unknown url type: https -- Some packages may not be found!  
working: Couldn't find index page for 'incremental' (maybe misspelled?)  
working: Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: unknown url type: https -- Some packages may not be found!
working: No local packages or download links found for incremental>=16.10.1
```

My github is at https://github.com/sergeLabo/androidserver2.
The full log is at https://github.com/sergeLabo/androidserver2/blob/master/log_0.45.txt.

Buildozer cannot find the incremental package. But at https://pypi.python.org/simple/incremental/, there are files incremental-16.10.1.tar.gz to incremental-17.5.0.tar.gz.

All other packages are ok with https: ... (sdl2, six, ..)

I have the same error with incremental-17.5.0.tar.gz in .buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/incremental or with incremental in requirements.

I also tried [How to build kivy and Twisted in Buildozer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48643295/how-to-build-kivy-and-twisted-in-buildozer).

System:

- Debian stretch 9.2
- python 2.7
- kivy-1.10.0
- buildozer-0.34
- cython-0.25.2 and cython-0.23

How to install incremental?

Comment: It looks a bit like your system is lacking HTTPS support: "unknown url type: https".  Are you missing an OpenSSL install?

Comment: Yes, but:
The following packages are installeted: openssl, libssl-dev, python-openssl

In the full log, we found for example:
[INFO]:    Downloading hostpython2 from https://python.org/ftp/python/2.7.2/Python-2.7.2.tar.bz2
working: Python-2.7.2.tar.bz2
Download 0.00% Download 0.07% .... etc ....

https works and doesn't seem to be the problem !

Comment: @serge: What is the ***Java version*** installed? Could you please share with us your ***buildozer.spec*** file? I presumed that the twisted programs are from the kivy-examples.

Comment: My java version is: java-8-openjdk-amd64. buildozer.spec at https://github.com/sergeLabo/androidserver2/blob/master/buildozer.spec,
and yes, twisted programs are from examples and works fine on my PC.

Answer (score 0):

I got twisted working in my app but ended up scrapping it because I was unable to restart the reactor once it stopped and just went with simple socket dials because all I needed was a simple client.  I think what I did to fix the incremental issue was download the incremental tar file and manually place it in a folder at .buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/incremental so that when buildozer checks to see if the file is downloaded it doesn't need to and can just use the one you've manually supplied.  It's been a couple months and I no longer have that revision saved so I'm not positive if that's how I fixed it but it would be a good thing to try.

Comment: I try to put incremental tar file in .buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/incremental
but strangely buildozer try always to download incremental ...

Finally, I use socketserver in my project.  But less powerful and practical than twisted!

Comment: Alright I think I found the solution that worked for me.  You need to build your app with Incremental included as a dependency first without twisted.  After incremental is built into your .buildozer build then go back and build with twisted included in your dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I got a valid apk with

first build :  requirements=incremental,kivy

second build : requirements=kivy,twisted

incremental isn't in ./buildozer/.../packages, but in ...python2.7...

GoBig06, thank's for this idea !